# How to upload only source files to github?

Tags: python, git, github

I have project written in python which i would like to upload to my github repo. In my source directory in laptop, there are other compiled python scripts (.pyc) residing as well which i would like to avoid uploading to github. The documentation avaiable on the internet shows  uploading entire source directory to github repo.

**Is there a way to avoid uploading certain file type, specifically *.pyc, to github repo?**

Comment: Can you please post the link of the documentation you're referring to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a [`.gitignore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) file and add `*.pyc` to it

I recommend you put this [standard .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) for python by github It has `*.py[cod]` to get rid of `.pyc`,`.pyo` and `.pyd` files

Comment: It may also be worthwhile to look at http://gitignore.io/, a web service that generates `.gitignore` files for various combinations of languages, operating systems and tools. It can also be integrated into your shell so you can do things like `gi python,java > .gitignore && gi eclipse > .git/info/exclude`.

Comment: Note that if you've already `git add`ded some `.pyc` files, creating a `.gitignore` won't retroactively remove them from your repo. You'll want to run `git rm -r *.pyc` at the top level of your repo to recursively delete and remove from your repo all `.pyc` files you've added.

Answer (score 1):

This is the intent of the [.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) file

For your specific problem, you should add `*.pyc` to this file.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload you files to github only what is in your git repo gets uploaded. pyc files should not have been added to your git repo anyways. If you did, remove them before pushing your repository.

You can use the .gitignore files to not let pyc files show up in your `git status` view.